# javascript/mongoose use async function in for loop have unexpected behavior?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have an async function named populateFavoriteItem in for loop :

```
   var result = [];
   for (var i = 0; i <array.length ; i++) {
        populateFavoriteItem(accountId,array[i],function(doc){
        result.push(doc);
        //mark 1
        })
      // if (i == array.length - 1) {
      // console.log(result);
      // callback(result);     
      // }  
   }
   //mark 2
   console.log(result);
   callback(result);
```

It always run mark 2 first and then run to mark 1. Therefore, I get a null result array. Seems that result is not the populateFavoriteItem callback function.

Im trying to write if() condition in the for loop but get the same consequence, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use Node.js eventEmitter:

```
   var result = [];
   var obj;
   var j = 0;
   var myEventEmitter = new eventEmitter;
   myEventEmitter.on('next',addResult);
   function addResult(){
      result.push(obj)
      j++;
      if (j == array.length) {
        callback(result);
      }
   }


   var populateFav = promiseify(populateFavoriteItem);           
   for (var i = 0; i <array.length ; i++) {
        var ii = i;
        populateFavoriteItem(accountId,array[ii],function(doc){
          //result.push(doc);
          obj = doc;
          myEventEmitter.emit("next");
        })
   }
```